# If $C\subseteq [0,1]$ is infinite, $\exists a$ s.t. $C\cap[a,1]$ is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I am asked to prove or disprove the following:

> Let $C\subseteq [0,1]$ be infinite. Then, there exists $a\in (0,1)$ s.t. $C\cap[a,1]$ is also infinite.

**My attempt:** Suppose that $C\cap[a,1]$ is finite for every $0<a<1$. Then, $C\cap[0,a)$ must be infinite. Consider an infinite sequence $c_1,c_2,c_3,...,c_n,...$ where $c_i\in C$ and $c_k<c_{k+1}$. By Archimedean property we can find $\frac{1}{n}=a<c_1$, such that $C\cap[a,1]$ is infinite, so we have a contradiction.

I'm not sure if I'm even allowed to do any of this, so I would appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Look at the sequence $a_n=1/n$.

Comment: @arugula I get that the idea is to "transfer" an infinite amount of elements of $C$ from $[0,a)$ to $[a,1]$, but I'm not sure how to express that. More specifically, I'm wondering what happens if $\inf C=0$.

Comment: No. The idea is that it is not true. That is what the sequence $1/n$ shows. For every $a\in(0,1)$, $[a,1]$ only contains finitely many elements of the sequence.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.

Comment: This is true if the infinite set was uncountable

Comment: The sequence $a_n = 1/n$ is a counterexample. Since the set $C = \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ has an infinite number of elements, and is clearly a subset of $[0,1]$ but there is no $a \in (0,1)$ so that $C \cap [a,1]$ is infinite

Comment: If for all $0\neq n\in\mathbb{N}$ you have that $C\cap[1/n,1]$ is finite, then $C\setminus\{0\}=\bigcup_{0\neq n\in\mathbb{N}}C\cap[1/n,1]$ is countable. This would imply that $C$ is countable. Therefore, if $C$ is uncountable, then there is some $a\in(0,1)$ such that $C\cap[a,1]$ is infinite.